# Htaccess Rewrite first name last name

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ profile.php?email=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How would I be able to pass through first name and last name variables, instead of the email variable?

Comment: Provide examples of URLs with first name, last name. Also how it should be rewritten to?

Comment: For example, a rewrite similar to https://www.facebook.com/joe.rogan, RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ profile.php?fname=$1 & lname=$2[QSA,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a new rule for `firstName.lastName`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?fname=$1&lname=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ profile.php?email=$1 [QSA,L]
```